# alert dialog not blocking UI on Firefox using a timeout

Tags: javascript, alert

I've searched but cannot find any documentation about this specific behaviour in Firefox.

If I wrap a call to alert method inside a timeout or an interval function in Firefox, the UI is not blocked. In all other browsers I have tested (chrome/IE/safari), the expected behaviour for a modal alert dialog occurs.

[SEE DEMO (test it in any browser, then Firefox)](http://jsfiddle.net/WaYpf/)

```
setTimeout(function () {
    alert("If you wait enough in Firefox, the UI is updated!");
}, 0);
```

Is there any documentation about this specific behaviour?

Comment: Documentation:  I observed the page rendering in Firefox 21.0 when an alert() was executed in a timeout.  That behavior did not occur in Safari 5.1.9

Comment: Why do you need documentation? You observed it happening. If you need documentation, cite my comment.

Comment: We need sometimes to block UI on certain condition. If it's an expected behaviour, i would like to know it. Of course, we could just set the alert() outside of any timeout/interval but have we to modificate code because of bug or an expected behaviour? This is the question.

Comment: You know usually bugs are fixed, expected behaviours are not... Does it make sense?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quoting bobince:

> In summary, JavaScript appears to most users, most of the time, to
>   have a strict event-driven single thread of execution. In reality, it
>   has no such thing. It is not clear how much of this is simply a bug
>   and how much deliberate design, but if you're writing complex
>   applications, especially cross-window/frame-scripting ones, there is
>   every chance it could bite you — and in intermittent, hard-to-debug
>   ways.

From this topic: [Is JavaScript guaranteed to be single-threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such thing as a *rendering standard*. Therefore, you should not expect all browsers to render identically.

The *expected behaviour* is what *you* expect, because you observed it in 3 other browsers. It has no meaning.